# How to clean up masscan output (-oG)

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have a problem with the output produced by the `masscan` utility with the `-oG` options ("grep-able" output); for instance, it outputs this:

```
# Masscan 1.0.3 scan initiated Wed Jun  4 01:35:02 2014
# Ports scanned: TCP(3;21-23,) UDP(0;) SCTP(0;) PROTOCOLS(0;)
Host: 192.168.100.19 () Ports: 2222/open/tcp////
Host: 192.168.100.13 () Ports: 2222/open/tcp////
Host: 192.168.100.16 () Ports: 443/open/tcp////
Host: 192.168.100.8 ()  Ports: 21/open/tcp////
Host: 192.168.100.5 ()  Ports: 22/open/tcp////
Host: 192.168.100.5 ()  Ports: 443/open/tcp////
Host: 192.168.100.16 () Ports: 80/open/tcp////
Host: 192.168.100.19 () Ports: 22/open/tcp////
Host: 192.168.100.7 ()  Ports: 80/open/tcp////
Host: 192.168.100.8 ()  Ports: 80/open/tcp////
Host: 192.168.100.12 () Ports: 2222/open/tcp////
Host: 192.168.100.13 () Ports: 22/open/tcp////
# Masscan done at Wed Jun  4 01:35:16 2014
```

The above is neither very readable nor easy to understand.

How can I use Linux command-line utilities, e.g. `sed`, `awk`, or `grep`, to output something as follows, using the file above?

```
Host: 192.168.100.5
Ports: 22, 443

Host: 192.168.100.7
Ports: 80

Host: 192.168.100.8
Ports: 21, 80

Host: 192.168.100.12
Ports: 2222

Host: 192.168.100.13
Ports: 2222, 22

......
```

As you can see, the output is much more readable in this layout:
sorted by IP address, with *all* associated ports listed below, consolidated across multiple input lines with the same IP address.

Comment: Is the single instance of a lack of a space after "Ports:" a typo of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F' +|/' '
  !/\s*#/ {    # ignore comment lines
      # Add the port on the current line to the associative array 
      # element for the IP address on the current line.
    ips[$2] = ips[$2] (ips[$2] == "" ? $5 : ", " $5)
  }
  END {
      # Enumerate all IPs and the ports for each.
      # Since the IPs will be listed in no specific order, the output
      # is piped as a _single_ line to "sort" in order to sort by IP address,
      # and then expanded into 2 lines via "tr".
    for (ip in ips) {
      printf "Host: %s@Ports: %s@\n", ip, ips[ip] | \
        "sort -t. -n -k 1.6,1 -k 2,2 -k 3,3 -k 4,4 | tr @ \"\n\""
    } 
  }
  ' file
```

- This solution properly *sorts the output by IP address* and separates the ports with commas.
- By contrast, for a given IP address, the *port numbers* are listed in the order they were encountered in the input (as in the sample output data in the question).

Comment: Hi, thanks for help, just what I was looking for. BTW I changed the $5 to $4 as for some reason it was skipping "()" and printing out "open" when there should of been a port number.

Comment: @BobbyB: Glad to hear it; also not sure why you had to change to `$4`, but since `$5` works with the sample input in your question, I'll leave it at `$5`; what `awk` version do you use?

Comment: `awk -W version`  result: `mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996`      Forgot to say I have completely no experience with awk or sed, and was also wondering how could you use the answer you've given in a bash shell script e.g. `./sort.sh somefile`

Comment: Strangely, when I run your _sample_ input data against `mawk 1.3.3`, it also works fine with `$5` - how does your actual data differ? As for invoking `awk` inside a script: it's no different from invoking it on the command line. What are you having difficulty with? Making the filename variable?

Comment: 1) Having $5 and using within the command line prints the ports section like so `Ports: open, open`
2)Yes, not really sure on how to make a filename variable.

Comment: Re 1): The only explanation I have is that your production data differs from the sample data in your question, but I guess we don't need to solve that problem. Re 2): If you invoke your script as `./sort.sh someFile`, then inside your script you can refer to string `someFile` as `$1` - generally, you'll want to double-quote variable references, so use `"$1"` - see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Special_Parameters_and_Variables

Comment: Much appreciated. Just finished creating the bash script :)